# How to make a radio button option required and pop up an error banner if no button checked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, required

I am currently working on an html form to collect some basic information. Yet I want the audience stating their gender and it is compulsory to do so. However, I have tried the "required" function but there is no error banner popped up when someone leaves it blank. It works well when input=text but not for radio buttons or a drop-down list. May I know what is the problem in my code? I have attached both HTML and Script code here. Thank you so much for your help!

```
<div class="hs_gender field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="gender-student">Gender of Students?*</label><br>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="gender_s" value="male" type="radio" value="" placeholder="" required data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="You cannot leave it blank.">M</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="gender_s" value="female" >F</label><br>
          
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
</div>
<div class="hs_email field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="studentemail">Your email?*</label>

          <input id="email-student" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" placeholder="example@gmail.com" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="You cannot leave it blank." >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
</div>
```

```
$(".next").click(function() {
        $(".steps").validate({
            errorClass: 'invalid',
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.next('span').children());
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).next('span').show();
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).next('span').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the attribute `required` working correctly, it needs to be inside a form, and you need a button (or input) of type submit.

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="hs_gender field hs-form-field">
    
    <label for="gender-student">Gender of Students?*</label><br>
      <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender_s" value="male" type="radio" value="" placeholder="" required data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="You cannot leave it blank.">M</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender_s" value="female" required>F</label><br>
    
    <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field">
  
    <label for="studentemail">Your email?*</label>

    <input id="email-student" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" placeholder="example@gmail.com" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="You cannot leave it blank." >
    <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes indeed i just paste part of my code here and it's in a form that works well. It just bother me a lot when the audience leave it blank but no error banner pop up. To illustrate u can check it out (https://gttutor.com/find-tutor/)  and click the next button you may have a better idea of what i mean. Thanks for your help @clod9353 !